# Remove Json encode Extra Brackets

Tags: json, wordpress

Dow do i remove extra braces from my JSON encode data ?

I am getting this snippet code

```
{"":""
  {
   "primary_name":"ram",
   "primary_email":"ram@ramu.com",
   "primary_password":"1234",
   "primary_confirm_password":"1234",
   "title":"demo",
   "description":""
  }
""}
```

I want my code to look like this

```
{
  "primary_name":"ram",
  "primary_email":"ram@ramu.com",
  "primary_password":"1234",
  "primary_confirm_password":"1234",
  "title":"demo",
  "description":""
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr.Bipin
Please try this.

```
$json_obj = {"":""
              {
                "primary_name":"ram",
                ...

                "description":""
              }
          ""};

$new_array = [];

foreach( $json_obj as $item ){
    if( $item != ""){
      array_push($new_array, $item);
    } else {
      continue;
    }
}
```